# Does gsutil mv command share files publicly in flight?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I've just moved around 33.7k files from a bucket's top-level to a subdirectory via

`gsutil -m mv gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/\*.json gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/dumps/`

While the files were in flight, my boss was in the webinterface of Cloud Storage and she saw that some files were shared publicly:

[image: GCS Webview]

I immediately checked the permissions for the listed files via `gsutil ls -L gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/dumps/[SOME_FILE].json`, but they looked fine after the move and before nothing was shared publicly.

After checking the [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv) I saw that there is a `-p` option to preserve ACLs. But I don't know if this would have prevented the situation as my default bucket ACL looks like this:

```
gsutil defacl get gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
[
  {
    "entity": "project-owners-xxx",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "xxx",
      "team": "owners"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-editors-xxx",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "xxx",
      "team": "editors"
    },
    "role": "OWNER"
  },
  {
    "entity": "project-viewers-xxx",
    "projectTeam": {
      "projectNumber": "xxx",
      "team": "viewers"
    },
    "role": "READER"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gsutil mv` has [the same options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/mv#options) by default than `gsutil cp`, and this command, by default, [does not copy the objects ACL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#copying-in-the-cloud-and-metadata-preservation).

The `-p` will take in account the ACL of each object. As the origin and destination bucket, in this case, are the same, you have to [set an ACL on the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) if you want to keep the files private.

Comment: Bucket ACLs != object ACLs.  Bucket ACLs control permissions on the bucket itself (viewing/updating metadata, listing objects within the bucket, etc).  You're confusing the bucket's ACLs with its "default object ACLs".  If you don't supply any object ACLs in your request to upload an object to a bucket, a default set of ACLs are applied to the object... thus the name "default object ACLs", sometimes shortened to "defacls".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot you provided, it seems you're in the top-level of the bucket (I assume the blue "s" in the top-left corner is from the word "Buckets", directly above the "Name" column).  In this case, you're looking at the objects that **have not been moved yet**.  After moving the objects from `gs://BUCKET/` to `gs://BUCKET/subdir/`, if your defacl as shown is correct, the objects under the `subdir/` prefix should not be publicly visible.

As for why your top-level objects were publicly viewable in the first place, your guess is as good as mine :)